# Retaining state of radio button

Tags: radiobuttonlist

I want to retain selected radio button value when user revisits the page.Is there any easy way to do this?
I am using radiobuttonlist to generate radio button options dynamically in code.

Comment: You can do that in many different ways (store the user selected values in local storage or database and retrieve it set the values again when user revisit). Are you facing any problem with your code or just asking for suggestion?

Comment: I am able to store the value in session but don't know how to set it back?